# Rails rescue standard error doesn't get sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, standard-error

I have a controller method as follows

```
def create
  @game = Game.create_new_game(game_params)
  render 'show', status: 200
rescue StandardError => e
  render json: {
    status: 500,
    error: e.to_s
   }
end
```

I added a `binding.pry` and I can clearly see the following error in my console:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Duration can't be blank>
```

But it still sends the `status:200` to the client side. Is there a different way the errors are supposed to be handled?

**EDIT:**

`create_new_game` method in `Game`

```
def self.create_new_game(prms)
  @player = Player.find(prms[:player].to_i)
  @game = @player.games.create!(
  name: prms[:name],
  duration: prms[:duration]
  )
  @game.save!
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not normally raise an exception when a record is invalid. Its only when you use the "bang" methods like `.create!` that an exception is raised. Its also impossible for us to know what is going on inside `Game.create_new_game`. These are used for example in seed files wherethe developer should be aware that the validation failed or in nested transactions where it should trigger a rollback.

But what you're doing is not a good practice since exceptions should be used for exceptional events - not normal control flow.

Instead you should check the return value of saving/updating the record and determine the response.

```
def create
  @game = Game.create(game_params)
  if @game.save
    status: :created, location: @game
    # or
    render json: @game
  else
    render json: {
      status: 500,
      error: @game.errors.full_messages
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: `rescue StandardError => e` is "Pokemon Exception Handling" (gotta catch them all) which is in itself also an anti-pattern. You should only rescue exceptions that you actually know what to do with or you'll end up masking bugs in the application.

Comment: I added the `create_new_game` method in the question. I'm not really catching the exception over here though, this is a `StandardError` so it should only catch the `errors` right?

Comment: So basically if I need to check for errors such as if `player with id exists` or if `all the validations passed` then I need to add a separate catch for all of them?

Comment: `@game.save` will run all the validations in the model and return false if its not valid. You may want to start with a basic rails tutorial as this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: You would "check if player with id exists" by adding a validation in the model.

Comment: All the validations already exist and I can view them being raised in the console. The thing I'm unsure about is how do we send the appropriate error raised through the `json render`

Comment: You're confusing two very different things - exceptions are a ruby language construct for handling program errors. Rails validations create an an errors object which contains the validations failures. Completely different things.

Comment: You get validation errors by `@game.errors` which is a hash like object. There are also methods like `.full_errors` which give an array of error messages. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: I understand your point, I was trying to find a way to display any kind of exception/error through the same render. But your methodolgy works

Comment: Rails already does that on the framework level. If you want to catch a particular error such as `ActiveRecord::NotFound` to provide a custom error page you use `rescue_from` in the controller which wraps the action in a `rescue`. But this is not applicable here.

Comment: Using rescue in your action instead is a really bad idea as it will swallow useful debugging information in development.